# How can I wrap React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to wrap a React node into this function:

```
export const foo = (WrappedComponent: *) => {
  class fooRenderer extends Component<any> {
    render() {
      const { bar, ...props } = this.props;

      if (bar) {
        ...
      }

      return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }
  }

  return fooRenderer;
};
```

I tried the following:

```
class MyWrappedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    ...
    return foo(
      <MyComponent
            a={a}
            b={b}
       </MyComponent>
    );
  }
}
```

and received the following error:

> *Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.*

So essentially I need to render `foo(Component_instance)`.

Comment: I think you can do this with inline statement condition and didn't need wrap the react component

Comment: @FarshadFahimi that makes sense, but I did simplify the code to post it here, so I'm really interested how to wrap component in the 1st place.

Comment: Isn't this just a HOC?

Answer (score 0):

you can create your react component out of the function

```
class fooRenderer extends Component{
   render(){
      return(
        <div>Component</div>
      )
   }
}
```

after that call the component in your function

```
export default function wrappedComponent(a, b){
   return <fooRenderer a={a} b={b}/>
}
```

react component at the deep is function if you like to know